# Filtering TFS Listitem based on groups (permissions)

Tags: tfs, tfs-workitem

I have a field in TFS that will have ALLOWEDVALUES that everyone can see. No problems there.  All listitems are displayed.

I now want to 'add' to the set of ALLOWEDVALUES based on whether a person is in a group of not.  I've created a new project group, created a new ALLOWEDVALUES rule that has the for set to the new project group.

When looking at the list of values now the list that gets displayed is empty.  What I want to see displayed are the listems from both ALLOWEDVALUES.  Is this possible?

code snippet:

```
<WHEN field="Field" value="Value">
 <ALLOWEDVALUES expanditems="true">
 <LISTITEM value="OM1" />
 <LISTITEM value="OM2" />
 <LISTITEM value="OM3" />
 </ALLOWEDVALUES>
 <ALLOWEDVALUES for="[project]\ModelTest" expanditems="true">
 <LISTITEM value="New Model 1" />
 </ALLOWEDVALUES>
```

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to do it this way:

```
<WHEN field="Field" value="Value">
  <ALLOWEDVALUES not="[project]\ModelTest" expanditems="true">
     <LISTITEM value="OM1" />
     <LISTITEM value="OM2" />
     <LISTITEM value="OM3" />
  </ALLOWEDVALUES>
  <ALLOWEDVALUES  for="[project]\ModelTest" expanditems="true">
     <LISTITEM value="OM1" />
     <LISTITEM value="OM2" />
     <LISTITEM value="OM3" />
     <LISTITEM value="New Model 1" />
  </ALLOWEDVALUES>
</WHEN>
```